# Slide multiple divs, only one show, others hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slidetoggle

I use `slideToggle()` for my ..read more/less content, they change it. How can I make only one hidden text to show up, so when I click them, the "old" hidden text slideUp, and the "new" show only.

```
var moreText = "... Read More",
lessText = "... Read Less";

$(".read_more").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.text($this.text() == moreText ? lessText : moreText)
        .prev(".more")
        .slideToggle("normal");
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide complete DHTML code and also if possible make a fiddle?

Comment: Without some indication about the HTML layout its hard to say, but you could try using the [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a slideUp for the other `.more` elements

```
$(".read_more").click(function () {
    var more = $(this).text(function(_,txt) {
        return txt == '... Read More' ? '... Read Less' : '... Read More';
    }).prev(".more");

    $('.more').not(more).slideUp().text('... Read More');
    more.slideToggle("normal");
});
```

Comment: Thanks guys, thanks @adeneo, only one thing, when it is "not(more)" the text need to be '... Read More' again.

Comment: Thank you guys, i find the problem in the _Jquery_ add after `var $this = $(this);`  - `$(".read_more").not($this).text(moreText);` 

  
and below just `$('.more').not(more).slideUp();`

If someone not get it, you can comment, thanks.